# Trying to center read more link on div hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created 2 content divs large and medium that I want to hover over and display a read more link, at the moment however Im having trouble actually centering the read more link in the middle of the div?

Also is there a better way to script this? Im learning js/jquery at the moment and trying to work out various things that may prove handy in projects.

Could code be written so that no matter what the container div size the read more will adapt to fit onto the center?

Source can be viewed here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/R9NNt/

Comment: Why not center on the mouse position, a bit below or above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Horizontal center the div by giving `width: 100%; text-align: center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/R9NNt/5/

and here for vertically.

http://jsfiddle.net/R9NNt/21/

here the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".large, .medium").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children(".content").fadeTo(200, 0.25).end().children(".hover").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children(".content").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        }
    ).each( function( index, item ) {
        var hover = $(this).find('.hover');
        var top = Math.round( ( $(this).find('.content img').outerHeight() - hover.outerHeight() ) / 2);
        hover.css('top', top + 'px');
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice technique but it doesn't center vertically

Comment: Vertically center now with jQuery for this very special case. It vertically centers according to the image only.

Comment: How can I make the whole hover area clickable to the readmore page?

Comment: this will need more changes on HTML an JS. let me see what I can do.

Comment: made an update to the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R9NNt/24/ - you may replace the alert of the url with `document.location.href = $(this...`

Comment: How I make the border at the top fade also when the div is hovered, can I apply this hover effect to .large somehow? Also if I add content above the image it knocks off the centering of the read more link?

Comment: Sure the centering will not work anymore I've updated the fiddle again http://jsfiddle.net/R9NNt/26/

Comment: Sorry wrong link, http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/CcZXA/ how can I make the border on the article also fade? Also adding content above the image puts the read more link out of position? Thanks

Comment: the fix for the center I posted some comments before!  jsfiddle.net/R9NNt/26

Comment: Thanks fo your help Daniel, if the border has to stay in the article tag is there any other ways of making the whole article fade on hover?

Comment: Maybe, there are tons of possibilities, but with your current HTML structure I don't see one.

Answer (score 0):

I added this css:

```
.hover, .medium{
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R9NNt/22/

any good for you?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to horizontally center by doing `width: 100%; text-align: center;` on the content div, but when it comes to CSS vertical centering it's a nightmare, particularly with liquid layouts/things that are of an unknown size.

As your sizes are known, it's worth taking a look a [Vertical centering with CSS](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) which details many examples of how to vertically center content. When dealing with liquid content, I'll let you into a little secret

> [**Give Up And Use Tables**](http://giveupandusetables.com/)
>  `<table><tr><td align="center" valign="center">Boo that was easy. Kick the table police in the balls and let's start doing something productive now.</td></tr></table>`