# jquery hover detecting image and centering hidden anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to learn jquery and currently working on a `fade in fade out` example content div, can anyone explain to me or provide any links to how the image is detected if there is one in the div and how the read more link is then centered there? I am prepared to wwo on this example myself, I just need a little direction on where I can fin tutorials/articles/videos etc

my current code for this is here http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/a4mPS/3/

Comment: I've put an update you can work with on your earlier post. . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971151/how-to-attach-a-show-method/5971190#5971190 here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4mPS/5/

Comment: It seems you keep asking the same questions. don't you look at the good solution you received yesterday for this similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/q/5947737/740699

Answer (score 0):

Here's some guidance to get some sizes out of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/j8NFB/2/ then you can use those sizes and some simple math to position the read more link.